# How can I make the display size smaller than the actual physical screen size?

Tags: display, screen

How can I make the display size smaller than the actual physical screen size?

Hello,

So the size of my laptop screen is about 13 inches.

I actually want to make the display smaller than the screen size.

So I am trying to create a thick black border around the display.

Is it possible to do this in Ubuntu?

Vesa

Comment: Yes, look up underscan. Depending on the video card you have there are different possiblities for the set up.

Comment: I did, found nothing

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 1):

The option which you are looking for is called "underscan/overscan".

You have two different possiblities.

There is **AMD** which allows you to handle it with this option:
[image: AMD catalyst Center underscan settings]

**And Nvidia:**
[image: Nvidia settings underscan]

Once you have done the settings on how small you want it to be, there are other options with xrandr to replace your screen on a different positions, if you don't want it to be centered.

Comment: I have ATI Radeon. But that looks like a Windows screenshot. This is ubuntu 15.

Comment: It's still the same settings, I'll adjust the screenshot

Comment: But how can I access those settings from Ubuntu? They are not in system settings as far as I know.

Comment: You have to install the appropriate driver. For you it's [amd](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).

Comment: I had the same problem and NVIDIA graphics cards and this solution worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Install Unity Tweak Tool by this command:
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

then go to Main Menu : System Tools > Preferences > Inity Tweak Tools > Fonts

from there you can adjust fonts and sizes
[image]